# Child state updated but not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component named Recently Opened. There are no props passed to the child component from parent component. The rendor method of parent component is:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <RecentlyOpened />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

The render method of child component(RecentlyOpened) looks like this:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className='outer-box'>
                {this.state.items.map(item => {
                    <div className='item-box'>
                        <img className='image' src={'/src/assets/' + item.imgURL} />
                        <div className='name  item-margin'>{item.name}</div>
                        <div className='id  item-margin'><b>SKU/ID: </b>{item.productId}</div>
                    </div>;
                })}
            </div >
        );
    }
```

Here *this.state.items* is populated from an API call. But even as the state is updated(I have checked this) after the API call returns the data, the UI inside the map function doesn't get displayed and just the empty div is rendered. Shouldn't the UI be updated once the state of child component changes?

Comment: You're not returning anything in your map call

Comment: I didn't think that there was an issue with the map function. Just to get a clear picture, we need to do this as JSX can't render array and hence we need to put a return statement inside the map function?

Comment: array::map callback *needs* to return *something* that is being mapped to. No return value in map callback equals array of undefined values.

Answer (score 0):

You  are not returning a value in your map loop. A simple fix is to replace the curly brackets with parentheses.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className='outer-box'>
            {this.state.items.map(item => (
                <div className='item-box'>
                    <img className='image' src={'/src/assets/' + item.imgURL} />
                    <div className='name  item-margin'>{item.name}</div>
                    <div className='id  item-margin'><b>SKU/ID: </b>{item.productId}</div>
                </div>;
            ))}
        </div >
    );
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't the outside return statement work? Since render() will be called after the state change so it should now return UI after the state change.

Comment: The outer return will return the results of the map call. But the map call never gives data to the outer return statement. That's why you're not seeing anything. It's like going to the supermarket. Just because the supermarket gets their products delivered to them doesn't mean you can find them in the store. they still have to fill the shelves themselves. The same goes for the map call. Just because it has the data doesn't mean it will show them automatically.